# Take files off Windows Mobile device when docked

Tags: batch-file, windows-mobile

I have an application running on a Windows Mobile 6 device. It stores its files in the \My Documents folder. Can WMDC take these files off the device when it's docked? As far as I can see it can only sync files from the PC to the device.

Or can batch script be used instead to go to the connected device's filesystem and copy the files? e.g copy \My Documents\file.csv C:\Users\user\Desktop

As far as I know batch scripts cannot access an external device's filesystem.

Comment: Why not? It is possible to access external devices system as long as it is `NTFS`

Comment: Windows command interpreter can't access files on a mobile device using [Media Transfer Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) (MTP). When it is possible to configure the mobile device to declare its storage as USB mass storage device which results on connection to PC on mounting the storage of the mobile device as drive with a drive letter assigned than a batch file could access the files on the device.

Comment: That makes sense. I had the connection as MTP but can change it to USB mass storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMDC is like ActiveSync and supports an OnCennect registry entry:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services\AutoStartOnConnect]
"OnConnect"="\"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe\" /c d:\\OnConnect\\install.bat"
```

The above entry makes a batch called d:\OnConnect\install.bat run on every connect of a Windows Mobile or Windows CE (4/5) based device.

Copy of my original post (http://hjgode.de/dev/tipps.html#PC%20ActiveSync%20can%20be%20used%20to%20automate%20tasks%20on):

=============================================

In this example, the batch file d:\OnConnect\install.bat will be launched every time a device connects via ActiveSync. If you use the itsutils, you can specify a list of commands executed against the connected device. In example, you can following install.bat (assuming that all tools and files are in d:\OnConnect).

```
@echo on
pause
d:
cd d:\OnConnect
pput -f -v _0000_comp_itcivacn2.cab "\DiskOnChip\Persistent Copy\CabFiles\_0000_comp_itcivacn2.cab" 
pput -f -v userApp_WCE4.ARMV4.cab "\DiskOnChip\Persistent Copy\CabFiles\IuserApp_WCE4.ARMV4.cab" 
pput -f -v sqlce.wce4.armv4.cab "\DiskOnChip\Persistent Copy\CabFiles\sqlce.wce4.armv4.cab" 
pput -f -v System_SR_enu.cab "\DiskOnChip\Persistent Copy\CabFiles\System_SR_enu.cab" 
pregutl @region.reg
pause "ReBoot ?"
preboot
pause "*************** Finished **************************"
exit
```

## These line copy some files to the device, change the registry with a regedit4 conform file, sync the time of the device to yours PC time and then perform a warmboot. Using the XDA tools there are many more possibilities. Especially usefull, as PocketPC devices do not support batch files on the device.

What I call here itsutils is a set of cmd line apps for PC that are provided with source code. These can be used to copy files from and to the device and do some other stuff remotely. See currently here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/wiki/XdaUtils and http://nah6.com/~itsme/cvs-xdadevtools/itsutils/readme.txt